# Violation of the existence and uniqueness theorem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Consider the initial value problem
>   $$\frac{dx}{dt} = x \ln x, x(t_0)=x_0, x_0\geq1. \ \ (1)$$
>   a) Show that $f(x) = x \ln x$ is not globally Lipschitz on $[1;\infty).$ 
>   b) Show that $(1)$ has a solution defined for all $t\geq t_0$.

**My attempt:** 
a) $f'(x) = \ln x +1$ is not bounded on $[1;\infty),$ hence $f(x) = x \ln x$ is not globally Lipschitz on $[1;\infty).$ 
b) Using separation of variables we get $x(t) = x_0^{e^{t-t_0}},$ which is defined for all $t\geq t_0$.

Doesn't this violate the existence and uniqueness theorem which says that if $f(x)$ is globally Lipschitz, there exist and unique of solution?

Comment: Sorry, but what is by what violated?

Comment: So, your theorem says that: If $f(x)$ is globally Lipschitz, then there exists a unique solution, is that correct?  If so, then your theorem doesn't say anything (positive or negative) about what happens when $f(x)$ isn't globally Lipschitz.  That is, if $f(x)$ is not globally Lipschitz, then your theorem simply doesn't give you any information one way or the other.